# windows 10 search does not show batch files

Tags: windows-10, windows-search

I recently upgraded to windows 10 enterprise edition. I have some batch files in my documents folder with extension "cmd". These batch files are not showing up in the search results. These show up if I click on search my stuff and Folders in other places to look. It is very irritating.

Search even finds out any other files stored in the the same folder. It was working on windows 8.1 and windows 7 earlier.

Comment: As a workaround, you can use run to execute the batch commands.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior has changed in the current windows 10 version. (I have 1803 version installed). Now the batch files are also showing up in the search results.